# Buscar falta de ID em duas tabelas WOOCOMMERCE

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

Preciso fazer um busca e retornar `todos os pedidos` que estejam com status `processando`, e que possuem a coluna `meta_value` em `vazio` ou `inexistente` em outra tabela.

1º - No wordpress, irei verificar todos os pedido realizados na tabela `wp_posts`.

2º - Nessa mesma tabela `wp_posts`, preciso filtrar todos os pedidos que estão com o status `wc-processing` na coluna `post_status`.

3º - Daí pego os IDs da tabela `wp_posts`, e vejo quais deles não existem na tabela `wp_postmeta` que tem como ID a coluna `post_id`.

4º - A coluna `post_id` da tabela `wp_postmeta`, pode possuir várias linhas com o mesmo ID, mas tenho que filtrar apenas as que possuem a coluna `meta_key` = `_correios_tracking_code`.

5º -´Por fim, devo retornar todos os posts, que não possuem a `meta_key` = `_correios_tracking_code`, mais os posts que possuem a `meta_key` = `_correios_tracking_code`, mas que estejam vazios.

**SQL:**

```
  Tabela wp_posts
    _________________________
    |  ID  |  post_status  |
    _________________________
    |  1   | wc-processing |
    -------------------------
    |  2   | wc-processing |
    -------------------------
    |  3   |    wc-fail    |
    -------------------------
    |  4   | wc-processing |
    _________________________


Tabela wp_postmeta
_______________________________________________________
|  post_id |          meta_key       |   meta_value   |
_______________________________________________________
|     1    | _correios_tracking_code |  PM353535353BR |
-------------------------------------------------------
|     1    |          _codex         |      Elite     |  
-------------------------------------------------------
|     2    | _correios_tracking_code |                |
-------------------------------------------------------
|     2    |          _codex         |      Elite     |  
-------------------------------------------------------
```

**Wordpress:**

```
add_filter( 'views_edit-shop_order', array( $this, 'shop_order_filters' ), 10, 1 );

public function shop_order_filters( $views ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $sql = "SELECT
          (DISTINCT p.ID)
        FROM
          $wpdb->posts p
        WHERE
          p.post_status LIKE 'wc-processing'
          AND p.post_type = 'shop_order'";
          

        $v= $wpdb->get_var($sql);
        $views = //FILTROS
        return $views;
  }
```